# Expand recurrence data of Outlook appointment and get list of occurence dates.

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

Is there any way to expand recurrence pattern and get list of dates that recurrence will occur.

```
 Outlook.RecurrencePattern pattern = aitem.GetRecurrencePattern();
```

I can only get Number of occurrence. I tired with this, But I am not clear with output.

```
DateTime sd = pattern.PatternStartDate;
DateTime st = pattern.StartTime;
var appo = pattern.GetOccurrence(sd + st.TimeOfDay);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Outlook only lets you retrieve occurrences by date. If you get the date wrong, `RecurrencePattern.GetOccurrence` will raise an exception.

If using Redemption is an option (disclaimer: I am Redemption developer), you can use [RDORecurrencePattern](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDORecurrencePattern.htm).`GetOccurrence` - unlike Outlook Object Model, it lets you pass either a date or an integer index as a parameter. You can also use [RDOFolder2](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOFolder.htm#rdofolder2).`GetActivitiesForTimeRange`

Comment: If we loop through all the dates and fill a list?
(lib you mention is not a free one :( no.)

Comment: You can loop through all dates, but if you have a yearly recurring appointment, getting an error 364 times out of 365 seems like a waste...